# java hacer un nuevo tipo de excepcion

Tags: java, excepciones

Buenas chicos os comento mi problema. Me encuentro practicando el tema de las excepciones en java y me he puesto a cambiar algunas de las validaciones que tengo para sustituirlas por excepciones pero tengo un problema y es que no se como implementar una segunda excepcion. Os enseño la parte del codigo donde tengo el problema:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean flag = false;
    float sueldo = 0;
    while (!flag) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduce el sueldo");
            sueldo = MyInput.readFloat();
            flag = true;

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Error. El valor introducido no es correcto. Intentelo de nuevo...");
        }
    }
}
```

Pues bien esa parte de la excepcion la tengo bien puesta y esta bien implementada. La idea es que en el caso de que el sueldo que se introduzca sea correcto (el valor sea numerico) se lance otra excepcion si el valor de esa variable es < 500. Ya he creado una nueva clase llamada "SalarioExcepcion" que hereda de la clase Exception pero no se como hacer para implementarla dentro del codigo que os he mostrado antes

```
public class SalarioExcepcion extends Exception{

  private float sueldo;

  public SalarioExcepcion(float sueldo) {
    super();
    this.sueldo = sueldo;
}

public String getMensaje() {
    String mensaje = null;

    if (this.sueldo <= 500) {
        mensaje = "Error. El sueldo del empleado ha de ser como MINIMO 501 €";
    }

    return mensaje;
}

}
```

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo si es que se puede?

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase excepción no necesita código, debería estar vacía, simplemente llamar a los constructores del padre (Exception). Por ejemplo:

```
public class SalarioExcepcion extends Exception {
    public SalarioExcepcion() {
        super();
    }

    public SalarioExcepcion(String mensaje) {
        super(mensaje);
    }
}
```

Y ahora que tienes tu excepción personal creada, vuelves al código en el que quieres que se produzca, y la lanzas con un throw si se incumple la condición. Además, la capturas en el try-catch.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean flag = false;
    float sueldo = 0;
    while (!flag) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduce el sueldo");
            sueldo = MyInput.nextFloat();
        if (sueldo <= 500) {
            throw new SalarioExcepcion();
        }

        flag = true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Error. El valor introducido no es correcto. Intentelo de nuevo...");
    } catch (SalarioExcepcion se) {
        System.out.println("Error. El sueldo del empleado ha de ser como MINIMO 501 €");
    }
}
```

}

Un pequeño detalle: En la descripción del error pones que el suelo debe ser como mínimo de 501€. Esto no es realmente cierto, porque es un float. Por tanto, al decir que quieres un valor <= que 500, el usuario puede introducir 500.5 y no daría excepción, ya que se cumpliría el mínimo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder la verdad es que visto asi es una tonteria pero hasta que lo entiendes y empiezas a ver por que falla no lo entiendes del todo. Lo dicho Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Saludos, tu segunda excepción se debe lanzar cuando ya has superado el problema de NumberFormatException, o sea ya que hayas construido tu sueldo, por lo que la SalarioExcepcion no contiene la logica de <= 500, si no el algoritmo que estás siguiendo.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws SalarioExcepcion{
boolean flag = false;
float sueldo = 0;
while (!flag) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Introduce el sueldo");
        sueldo = MyInput.readFloat();
        if( sueldo <= 500)
              throw new SalarioExcepcion("Error. El sueldo del empleado ha de ser como MINIMO 501 €");
        flag = true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Error. El valor introducido no es correcto. Intentelo de nuevo...");
    }
   }
```

Mientras que la exception luciría mas o menos asi:

```
public class SalarioExcepcion extends Exception {
    public SalarioExcepcion() { super(); }
    public SalarioExcepcion(String message) { super(message); }
    public SalarioExcepcion(String message, Throwable cause) { 
        super(message, cause); 
    }
    public SalarioExcepcion(Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
}
```

Para mayor informacion te dejo [esto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) (espero no te moleste el inglés)

Comment: Siii perfecto Muchas Gracias por todo :)